# How to create a sorted NSArray from an NSSet that contains arbitrary objects?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsset

I have an NSSet that contains many different types of objects. Typically it will contain some combination of NSDictionaries, NSStrings, NSArrays, and Classes, i.e. the objective-c "Class" type.  I need a way to produce an NSArray containing all of the objects in this NSSet, but is sorted so that it will always be in the same order for any set containing the same objects.  To be specific, by "same object" I mean by value, not by address.  It doesn't matter how it's sorted, as long as it's consistent.

I haven't found a way to do this so far.  I can't find any way of doing an ordered comparison between two arbitrary objects. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could potentially use the object's `hash` and then for any collisions maybe you could additionally sort by the objects class' `hash`

Comment: @Paul.s What `hash`?  Are you thinking about java?

Comment: @trojanfoe `hash` is defined as part of the `NSObject` protocol — see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash — it's used by `NSDictionary` and others.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's defined in the [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGFFCH) protocol

Comment: @Paul.s That is the way to go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects are derived from `NSObject`, so you could simply sort by `[NSObject description]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description)) which will be a summary of the object contents.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Paul.s in the comment; `hash` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)) is the way to go (it will be quicker to compare).

Comment: ... and he'd want to make sure he'd implemented `description` on any custom classes so that doesn't end up indirectly comparing by pointer.

Comment: @Tommy He doesn't mention custom classes in his question, only standard classes.

Comment: I was jumping off his use of the word 'typically'.

Comment: Sorting by hash will work, but won't be stable if there happen to be hash collisions (with such heterogeneous objects you might be at higher risk for that). Depending on how serious an application this is, you may consider finding a secondary ordering principle (like `-description`) to help break ties here as well.

Comment: Also note that hash is really only guaranteed to be stable during single run sessions of an application: they're not guaranteed to be fixed for identical objects forever. If you're persisting this set over multiple versions of iOS/Mac and expect those hashes to be consistent over time, I'd be wary.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using either `hash` or `description` for accomplishing this. I got it working by using `hash` and resolve hash collisions with `description`, as you all suggested.

Comment: @BenZotto I think for my purposes `hash` will be fine.  For right now it just needs to be consistent between application invocations in the short term. Thanks for mentioning that it could change, though, since if I ever need it to be long term I'll find an alternative method.